# Check if a List<String> contains all element from a List<Object> using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 lists:

```
List<String> authorizedList ; // ["11","22","33"]
List<MySerial> serials; // [Myserial1,Myserial2,Myserial3] =>
```

MySerial are object with 2 parameters, Myserial(String serial, String name)

I want to check if all serial from serials are in authorizedList using stream but I'm new using it.

```
if (!serials.stream().map(MySerial::getSerial).anyMatch(authorizedList::equals)) {
    throw new UnauthorizedException();
}
```

But it always throw exception.

Comment: Use `allMatch` and `List.contains`. Example `serials.stream().map(MySerial::getSerial).allMatch(authorizedList::contains)`

Comment: See the `List.containsAll` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `authorizedList::equals` to `authorizedList::contains`.

Also you can invert the if statement from `anyMatch` to `allMatch`.

E.g. after the suggestions you should have:

```
if (!serials.stream().map(MySerial::getSerial).allMatch(authorizedList::contains)) {
    throw new UnauthorizedException();
}
```

Comment: @Eritrean fixed. thx for pointing it out

Comment: in the event that authorizedList can be big, I would suggest first making it a Set to improve the performance of contains: `Set<String> authorizedSet = authorizedList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())` and then change `authorizedList::contains` to `authorizedSet::contains`